# Possible to specify which text index field to search in MongoDB on a REST call using Eve?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, full-text-search, pymongo, eve

I'm allowing the user to type in a text query for searching for specific documents in my 'names' collection in MongoDB. I'm using 'Eve' for the API layer that connects my React frontend to my mongoDB. I have specified the text index along with what fields should be text searchable in the following code:

```
'mongo_indexes' : {
        'text': ([
            ('names.firstName.text', 'text'),
            ('names.middleName.text', 'text'),
            ('names.lastName.text', 'text'),
        ])
    }
```

This will allow the user to get all the documents back that have the user specified text query in all three of these fields. However, in cases where I only want to do a text search on one of these three fields, how could I go about handling this without having to create and re-create the text index? For this will slow down database performance. Can I change the mongo_indexes and which fields to use a REST call for example?

Comment: Just make three independent index, one for each field.

Comment: Any time you change an index, it has to be rebuilt, which takes processing time and power.  So modifying an index would not net you any performance gains.

Comment: You can only have one text index specified at a time

Comment: `mongodb` allows for multiple index to be defined.  Not sure why you would say that is not the case.  I have productional and developmental environments that work like this.

Comment: Yes, mongodb allows multiple indexes.  However, a text index is special, as noted in [Text Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/index.html#text-indexes) `IMPORTANT:  A collection can have at most one text index.`